# Converting Formulas in Multiple Worksheets to Values

Tags: vba, excel

The below VBA code is intended to convert formulas in multiple worksheets to values, then save a copy of the workbook in the specified directory.

I'm trying to copy paste value only, but the workbook still saves with formulas in these sheets. I don't know what I did wrong,this code doesn't seem to work

```
Sub CREATE4SHEETS()
Sheets(Array("sheet1", "sheet3", "sheet6", "sheet7", "sheet8", "sheet10")).Select
Sheets("sheet10").Activate
Sheets(Array("sheet1", "sheet3", "sheet6", "sheet7", "sheet8", "sheet10")).Copy

Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
ChDir "\\mac\desktop\" ' Name folder    
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "\\Mac\Desktp\newworkbook.xlsx" _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False ' need to change the name of the folder
ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

It seems that

```
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

is not working as supposed to. Does anyone know why? thanks!

Comment: Are you trying copy sheet to another file?

Comment: yes, selected sheets from one workbook to another in a directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below modified code will convert any formulas in the indicated worksheets to values, then save the workbook with the specified filename.

```
Sub CREATE4SHEETS()
Dim WS as Worksheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'For each WS in Sheets(Array("sheet1", "sheet3", "sheet6", "sheet7", "sheet8", "sheet10"))
'    WS.UsedRange.Value2 = WS.UsedRange.Value2
'Next WS

For each WS in Worksheets
    If (UBound(Filter(Array("sheet1", "sheet3", "sheet6", "sheet7", "sheet8", "sheet10"), WS.Name)) > -1) Then
        'Keep this worksheet
        WS.UsedRange.Value2 = WS.UsedRange.Value2
    Else
        WS.Delete
    End If
Next WS

Set WS = Nothing

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "\\Mac\Desktp\newworkbook.xlsx" _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False ' need to change the name of the folder
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: this code saves down extra sheets that I don't need in the original workbook as well.

Comment: @Sailormoon edited to provide an answer that will delete all other sheets.

Comment: Hi Nick thanks very much, would you also know how to avoid the message says there's already a copy? I want to default it to be save as overwrite. I will accept the answer as soon as I knock this last piece out. Thank you!

Comment: also there's a delete message box show up said you can't undo deleteting sheets, are you sure you want to delete..

Comment: @Sailormoon - You can use `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` to prevent both dialog boxes (delete and save). See edit above.

Comment: the file kept crashing on me when i put application.displayalerts =false at the end of the code.

Comment: @Sailormoon The line at the end of the code should be `Application.DisplayAlerts = True`; this reverts the display alert settings set to False at the beginning of the code. Does this solve your issue?

Comment: maybe its just my computer. I will check with other computers. Would you please also take  a look at this post if you know vbs?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35758090/vbs-not-running-at-all