# VBS not running at all

Tags: excel, vbscript

I'm using this vbscript to trigger a macro to run in an Excel without openning the excel.

```
sub test()
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
curDir = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")

Set myxlApplication = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
myxlApplication.Visible = False
Set myWorkBook = myxlApplication.Workbooks.Open("\\Mac\Home\Desktop\TEST.xlsm" ) 'Change to the actual workbook that has the Macro
myWorkBook.Application.Run "Module1.Macro1()" 'Change to the Module and Macro that contains your macro
myworkbook.save
myxlApplication.Quit
end sub
```

It's not working like it's supposed to, macro didn't run and even if I change the code to:

```
myWorkBook.Application.Run "Module1.Macro1()"
```

to some macro name that doesn't exist, this vbs is supposed to send me an error msg. But not even error msg shows up. Not sure why vbs is not running, I just double click the vbs file to run.

Please double note that,
Even if I code anything wrong, it wont even me any error msg. Which is odd

Comment: Have you tried `Call Macro1`?

Comment: where to put Call Macro1?

Comment: Instead of `myWorkBook.Application.Run "Module1.Macro1()"`

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realized that the macro is in a different WB

Comment: try this `myxlApplication.Run "Macro1"` ...  Wait, are you running this on a Mac? Or Windows? If a Mac, VBS scripts do not run on Mac.

Comment: windows,its a parallel system @Scott Holtzman, it was working before, and now my point is, the vbs is not running, if anything is wrong, it won't even give me error msg

Answer (score 1):

I was so stupid to put sub test(), end sub in vbs, vbs does not recognize the code.

Comment: VBScript does recognize the code, but you actually need to call it (`Sub test : ... : End Sub : test`).

Comment: You need to call the procedure (the sub) you defined in you VBScript. Just put a line `test` above or below the actual sub.